# Confused by a proof for the Baire Category Theorem for $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Im reading chapter9 Category, Real Analysis, Carothers, 1ed, talking about discontinuous functions of metric space. Here is a proof of the Baire Category Theorem for $\mathbb R$,:

[image]

Why can we find the interval $I_n$ with diam($I_n$)<1/n? I mean how to guarantee that the diam of $I_n$ will be less than 1/n? In other words, can I claim that the diam($I_n$)<$\sqrt(1/n)$ or something less? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly claim that $\operatorname{diam}(I_n)\le\frac1{\sqrt n}$ for each $n\ge 1$. More generally, given any sequence of positive numbers $a_n,$ we can make $\operatorname{diam}(I_n)\le a_n$ for each $n\ge1,$ but we want a (nice) sequence of positive numbers that converges to $0,$ so that we can use the Nested Interval Theorem.

The kicker, here, is that we can always find a smaller interval if need be. For example, let's say that we have found an open interval $I_2'$ such that $\overline{I_2'}\subset I_1\cap G_2\subset I_0\cap G_1\cap G_2.$ If $I_2'=(a,b),$ then putting $b=\min\{b,a+\frac12\},$ we have that $I_2:=(a,b')\subset I_2',$ and so $I_2$ is an open interval of diameter no greater than $\frac12,$ such that $\overline{I_2}\subset I_1\cap G_2\subset I_0\cap G_1\cap G_2.$

The same idea can be used for $n\ge 2.$

Comment: Can we find such a $G_n$ in $\mathbb R$ that is both open and dense?

Comment: Sure. For each integer $n\ge 1,$ let $$A_n=\left\{\frac1k\mid k\in\{1,...,n\}\right\},$$ and put $G_n=\Bbb R\setminus A_n.$

Comment: "\midk" is what?

Comment: Refresh the page. I had a typo.

Comment: Ohhhhh, awesome